# Calculate the difference between non-consecutive numbers (first instance from list)

Tags: r, string, indexing

I have a column in a data.frame where each observation is a string of numbers (e.g. "1,5,6,7,0,21"). I am attempting to calculate the difference for the first instance of non-consecutive numbers.  In the above example the result would be `5 - 1 = 4`. However, with the code I currently have I get `6`.  If my input is "1,2,0,21" I get the correct result of `21 - 2 = 19` (the numbers are sorted before subtraction occurs). I thought maybe the zero was the issue, but adding one to all values did not solve the issue. Perhaps a problem with my indexing? Any suggestions?

```
# find distance between number in first gap of non-consecutive numbers
b <- c("1,5,6,7,0,21") # does not work as desired result is 6 instead of 4
# b <- ("1,2,0,21") # works as desired

b.Uncomma <- sort(unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(b, split=","))))) # remove commas, remove duplicates, sort
#b.Uncomma <- b.Uncomma + 1 # same result
b.Gaps <- c(which(diff(b.Uncomma) != 1), length(b.Uncomma)) # find where the difference is not 1
b.FirstGap <- b.Gaps[1:2] # get the positions/index on either side of the first gap
b.Result <- b.Uncomma[(b.FirstGap[2])] - b.Uncomma[(b.FirstGap[1])] # subtract to get result
```

Comment: In 'c("1,2,0,21")' wouldn't the first instance of non consecutive numbers be 2, 0 ? Giving you 0 - 2 = -2 ?

Comment: Yeah, I think a bit more precise explanation needs to be added.

Comment: @epwalsh I guess it may be the one after the `sort`

Comment: This is what I'm thinking: ```diff(x)[which(diff(x) != 1)[1]]``` where ```x``` is your ```b.Uncomma```

Comment: @epwalsh this achieves the desired result in less lines of code. And for understanding, `diff(x)` finds the difference between entries, and `[which(diff(x) != 1)[1]]` find the first instance of non-consecutive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inp <- scan(text=b,sep=",")
#Read 6 items
 sinp <- sort(inp)
 diff(sinp)
#[1]  1  4  1  1 14

> diff(sinp)[diff(sinp) != 1][1]
#[1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 b.Uncomma <- sort(unique(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(b, split=","))))) # remove commas, remove duplicates, sort
 b.Gaps <- c(which(diff(b.Uncomma) != 1), length(b.Uncomma)) # find where the difference is not 1
 b.FirstGap <- b.Gaps[1] # get the positions/index of the first gap 
 b.Result <- b.Uncomma[(b.FirstGap+1)] - b.Uncomma[(b.FirstGap)] # subtract to get result
 b.Result
```